# string converted to NSURL and stored as property successful, later returns nil

Tags: xml-parsing

I am parsing strings from a feed, converting them to URL, and storing them as a property of FeedItem.  Initially, they are successfully converted to URL and stored, but later, when I access the property, it is nil.

FeedItem.h

```
@interface FeedItem : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* author;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL* imageURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* datePublished;

@end
```

Parser.m

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
// Custom blog object initialized here
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
    self.blogEntry = [[FeedItem alloc] init];
}

// Parse image URL that accompanies some blog entries
self.blogEntry.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
if ([[NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]] isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
    NSLog( @"converted to a url" );

    if ([self.blogEntry.imageURL isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
        NSLog(@"property of object is url");
    }else if (!self.blogEntry.imageURL) {
        NSLog(@"url becomes nil");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"property of object is NOT url");
    }
}
}
```

This prints "converted to a url" and "property of object is url" every time it should.  However, later in the same file:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
    // An individual blog has been parsed and a pointer to it is added to the parsedResults array

    if ([self.blogEntry.imageURL isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
        NSLog( @"URL passed" );
    }else if (!self.blogEntry.imageURL) {
        NSLog( @"is nil" );
    }else{
        NSLog(@"no luck");
    }

    [self.parsedResults  addObject:self.blogEntry];

}
}
```

This prints "is nil" every time.

Here is an example of one of the URLs being parsed:
url='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-HlNeYKf6Jyk/URKJ0NzA_kI/AAAAAAAAADY/AAkM6mNITlo/s72-c/Ananya's+Illustration.jpg'

I know there can be issues if a URL has a special character, but because it is successful at first, I figured this shouldn't be the issue.

I'm new to objective-c...what am I missing??

Comment: If instead of else if (!self.blogEntry.imageURL) you change that to else if (!self.blogEntry), does it still log "is nil"?

Comment: @rdelmar No, it logs the third option "no luck." The rest of the properties are properly stored and I can access them later to display in a UITableView without issue.

Comment: Where you have this: NSLog(@"property of object is url"); Try also logging self.blogEntry.imageURL and see if it looks like a proper URL.

Comment: Can you give an example of the feed you are parsing?

Comment: @zenopolis I'm parsing this: http://blog.solstice-mobile.com/feeds/posts/default

Comment: That link didn't lead anywhere for me. To debug your problem and provide the answer below I used http://jsblog.solstice-mobile.com/feeds/posts/default as my example.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `self.blogEntry` is getting deallocated.

This line:

`self.blogEntry = [[FeedItem alloc] init];`

is replacing what was previously at `self.blogEntry`.  Is it possible your parser calls this more than once before calling the "didEndElement" method?

Or, is `blogEntry` specified as a `strong` property on `self`?  If not, it could get deallocated at the end of the method after it's created.

Comment: It does not call it more than once before finding the end tag as far as I can tell since the allocation happens when it finds the start tag and there won't be another <entry> tag until the current one is closed (which calls "didEndElement"). blogEntry is specified as strong

Answer (score 0):

Your following piece of code does not guarantee that the blogEntry object is actually created.

```
// Parse image URL that accompanies some blog entries
self.blogEntry.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
if ([[NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]] isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
    NSLog( @"converted to a url" );

    if ([self.blogEntry.imageURL isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
        NSLog(@"property of object is url");
    }else if (!self.blogEntry.imageURL) {
        NSLog(@"url becomes nil");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"property of object is NOT url");
    }
}
```

You are creating the blogEntry object only when the start element is "entry" but you are accessing it outside that block without any check. It's NOT guarantee that when you try to set the image URL the blogEntry object is created.

Though this does not explain why your imageURL object is valid in didStartElement callback and NOT in didEndElement callback. I am just saying it's error prone.

Comment: won't blogEntry always be in existence once the first entry start tag is found? It's created when the start tag is found, but never "destroyed"...it just becomes a new object once another start tag is found. Still, I see your point...what's the best way to check this? Something like `if (self.blogEntry != nil) ...`?

Answer (score 0):

In your `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` method you are setting self.blogEntry.imageURL for every single element. Some elements won't contain a url attribute, and when a dictionary does not contain a specific key it returns `nil` - wiping out any value you previously stored there.

To overcome this you need code something like this:

```c
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // Custom blog object initialized here
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
        self.blogEntry = [[FeedItem alloc] init];
    }

    // Only allow the element containing the url we want to effect the value
    // of imageURL through
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media"]) {

        self.blogEntry.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]];
        if ([[NSURL URLWithString:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]] isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
            NSLog( @"converted to a url" );

            if ([self.blogEntry.imageURL isKindOfClass:[NSURL class]]) {
                NSLog(@"property of object is url");
            }else if (!self.blogEntry.imageURL) {
                NSLog(@"url becomes nil");
            }else{
                NSLog(@"property of object is NOT url");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Consider looking into breakpoints in Xcode to help debug this type of problem.

Comment: simply inserting the if statement you added didn't make a difference- it was never true.  I didn't think the URLs were in a tag unique to them...are you certain "media" is correct? Is there another way to check for an image URL? Also, I played with breakpoints but couldn't make heads or tails of what was being shown in the debug window. I do think the checking if the URL exists might be the key though...